# How can I list replay of 'ls /usr/share/applications' in python

Tags: python3

How can I list all .desktop files in usr/share/applications using 'ls /usr/share/applications' command and make it a list variable in python3.7?

like

```
list1 = replayof('command')
print1 = list(list1)
print(print1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not trivial to understand your question, and it's probably the wrong stackexchange for this, because it's more python than Ubuntu.

That being said, I believe the code you are looking for is

```py
import os
print(os.listdir('/usr/share/applications'))
```

Unless your question is really about how to list all files that end in `.desktop`? Then it would be

`ls /usr/share/applications/*.desktop`.

For more on this, you may want to look into `wildcards` and `globbing`.

I'll leave the list part as an exercise to the reader.